# Conditional Mathematical Expectation (problem)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that $X \sim CUD(0,1)$ and $Y \sim CUD(0,X)$, where CUD means continous uniform distribution, what is $E(X|Y)$ ?

I can't find density function $f(x,y)$. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I suppose that you mean to say "$Y|X=x \sim CUD(0,x)$". Then the density of $X$ is $f(x)=1_{0<x<1}$ (and zero oitside that interval) while the conditional density of $Y$ (given $X=x$) is given by $g(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}\cdot 1_{0<y<x}$ (and zero outside that interval) .Then you can find the joint density in the usual way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by [kjetil b halvorsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32967/kjetil-b-halvorsen).

I suppose that you mean to say $Y|X = x \sim CUD(0,x)$. Then the density of $X$ is $f(x)=1_{0<x<1}$ (and zero outside that interval) while the conditional density of $Y$ (given $X=x$) is given by $g(y|x)=\frac{1}{x}\cdot 1_{0<y<x}$ (and zero outside that interval). Then you can find the joint density in the usual way!